# Magento2.0 import the customers using CSV or Programmatically?

Tags: import, magento-2.0

HOw to import the customers using csv in magento 2.0?first i am try to export the existing customer in magento 2.0 and chnages the data in csv and import again,at the importing section importing is successfully done.But the New imported customers is not added in Customer->All Customers in Admin.Please give me any solution

Comment: plz reindex its work well.....

Answer (score 0):

You have successfully imported all customer and new customer has been added in database. Those new customers are not showing in grid because may be you have not performed reindex. **I suggest you to perform reindex** and than this may show in grid.